# WordPress contact form 7 text value change

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

**WordPress - Contact Form 7**

I am trying to find out the filter to modify the cf7 field value when someone enter values in it.

when user type in textfield and submit data,

1. validate - I had done
2. should not goto thank you page if invalid entry - I had done
3. replace text field with new data - Not Done

**Eg: 1**

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'your_validation_filter_func_tel', 100, 2 );
function your_validation_filter_func_tel( $result, $tag ) {

    $Yourvalue = $_POST['your-number'];
    if ( strlen( $Yourvalue ) == 2 ) {
        $result->invalidate( 'your-number', "Please enter a valid number.  " . );
        // HERE I WANT TO REPLACE NEW DATA TO TEXT FIELD
        $result->data( 'your-number', '1002' );
    } else if ( strlen( $Yourvalue ) == 3 ) {
        $result->invalidate( 'your-number', "Please enter a valid name." . );
        // HERE I WANT TO REPLACE NEW DATA TO TEXT FIELD
        $result->data( 'your-number', '1003' );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Eg: 2**

another working example

everything working except `$result['tel'] = $tel_cleaned_final;`

```
    <?php

    function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel ) 
    {

        // Initialization and Clean Input
        $tel_cleaned         = strtr( $tel, array(' '=>'', '-'=>'', '.'=>''));
        $tel_cleaned_trimmed = ltrim(strtr( $tel_cleaned, array('+'=>'')), '0');


        /* Test Conditions.
           I concluded 3 if conditions to 1 below bcaz the validation is working perfect
        */
        if ('test conditions here')
        $tel_cleaned_final = substr($tel_cleaned_trimmed, 2);
        else
        $tel_cleaned_final = $tel_cleaned_trimmed;



        if (strlen($tel_cleaned_final) == 10)
        {
        $result = true;

        //$result['tel'] = $tel_cleaned_final; 
        /* 
        Here i want to return new number to text box
        for eg: +91 98989-89898 returns  9898989898
        */

        }
        else
        {
        $result = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel', 10, 2 );

    ?>
```

Comment: Your question is very broad. I suggest looking at the [official documentation](https://contactform7.com/docs/) and the [hook documentation](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/#index=a)

Comment: @janw what I want is very simple, the instance name to change the form value

Comment: @J.K can you please share your contact form code?

Comment: @MukeshPanchal please see Eg: 2

Comment: Contact Form 7's action hooks don't allow for changing input fields. You'll have to add a DOM event that triggers on error and then check and update the fields in the DOM as necessary via JavaScript instead. See https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: You needs to change value via JS there is no function which will change field value in validation.

Comment: @Nadav thanks for the reply. Is it possible to do in DOM the same validation and return methods used in action hooks. If false form do not submit, If true change value and proceed.

Comment: @MukeshPanchal Thanks for the prompt reply. how to return error or input using JS. If false input - form do not submit, If true - change value and proceed.

Comment: @J.K No. Validation in JavaScript doesn't work the same way. You have a couple of choices here. Option number 1: disabling the submit button on page load and using an input event on the name field that will validate it on input (and only enable the submit button if the input is valid). Option number 2: use the DOM events available via the Contact Form 7 API to add text to an invalid field after the plugin's PHP validation has occurred. Either way you will need to use JavaScript instead of PHP. If you must use PHP perhaps Contact Form 7 is not flexible enough for your use-case.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do cannot be done with only the validation filter. Because that just outputs true or false based on the validations performed. To do what you want, you have to use another filter ( '**wpcf7_posted_data**' ) that has the value you want to filter. So we can break down our process into two steps.

**Step 1:** Do all the validation like you are currently doing.

Using your **Example 2**.

```
function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel )
{
    // Initialization and Clean Input
    $tel_cleaned         = strtr( $tel, array(' '=>'', '-'=>'', '.'=>''));
    $tel_cleaned_trimmed = ltrim(strtr( $tel_cleaned, array('+'=>'')), '0');

    /* Test Conditions.
       I concluded 3 if conditions to 1 below bcaz the validation is working perfect
    */
    if ('test conditions here')
    $tel_cleaned_final = substr($tel_cleaned_trimmed, 2);
    else
    $tel_cleaned_final = $tel_cleaned_trimmed;

    if (strlen($tel_cleaned_final) == 10)
    {
        $result = true;
    } else
    {
        $result = false;
    }

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel', 10, 2 );
```

The above code will make sure that your points 1 and 2 are working.

1. Validate.
2. Stop submission if entry is invalid.

**Step 2:** Re-run your tests to get the desired value and update it.

```
function sr_change_updated_field_value( $posted_data ) 
{ 
    // Initialization and Clean Input
    $tel_cleaned         = strtr( $tel, array(' '=>'', '-'=>'', '.'=>''));
    $tel_cleaned_trimmed = ltrim(strtr( $tel_cleaned, array('+'=>'')), '0');

    /* Test Conditions.
       I concluded 3 if conditions to 1 below bcaz the validation is working perfect
    */
    if ('test conditions here')
    $tel_cleaned_final = substr($tel_cleaned_trimmed, 2);
    else
    $tel_cleaned_final = $tel_cleaned_trimmed;

    // Use the name of your field in place of "tel"
    $posted_data['tel'] = $tel_cleaned_final;

    return $posted_data;
}; 
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'sr_change_updated_field_value', 10, 1 );
```

**P.S.** This will update the values sent in the email, or in the submissions if you store them. It will show the validation message, but it will not show the updated value in text field because that cannot be done with php in this scenario.

**P.S. 2** This is all tested code. Happy Coding.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in CF7 v 5.0.5. If I put a 'die();' right after the function name, and submit the form, the die() never happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please update the plugin ? current version is 7.5.1.1 although i don't think that these filters were added recently. I can't get the version 5.0.5 to test it on that.

Comment: Contact Form 7 is at version 5.1.1, according to the WP repository page. I have not upgraded to 5.1x because of issues with how it forces use of reCAPTCHA v3, and that effect on load time and reCAPTCHA load on entire site (also, see their support forum for massive number of complaints about increased spam).

Comment: Ah. My Bad. You are right about the version. I misinterpreted it. But i remember testing it at the time of posting this solution. But i don't have time and resources to test this ATM.

Comment: However, i sure can guide you about the die() you are doing. It happens, but you do not notice it because, in filters die stops execution but it does not disrupt anything. Which means probably form would not submit but nothing on the front end will happen that shows the function died.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'some_function_name', 1 ); 
function some_function_name( $contact_form ) {
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $data = array();
        $data['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $firstName = $data['posted_data']['first-name']; // just enter the field name here
        $mail = $wpcf7->prop('mail');

        if($firstName =''){
            $mail['body'] = str_replace('[first-name]', $firstName . '-blah blah', $mail['body']);
        }

        $wpcf7->set_properties(array(
            "mail" => $mail
        )); 

        return $wpcf7;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

P.S. This is not tested, please let me know if it works :)