# Accessing CF7 tags from file.php

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm new to php and wordpress but need to rename the file uploaded via contact form 7 using the tags/fields entered elsewhere on the form.

I can see how to rename the uploaded file in "file.php", but the array holding the other parameters is in another php file.
Is anyone familiar enough with contact form 7 to give me some guidance on here? I'm afraid I'm not getting much support on the CF7 support page.

Answer (score 0):

Like I understand You want to rename file which is uploading by user using form - so You don't need to change code of *file.php*, write instead custom function in *../contact-form-7/includes/functions.php* and add hook for it like:

```
// define the wpcf7_submit callback 
function action_wpcf7_submit( $instance, $result ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_submit', 'action_wpcf7_submit', 10, 2 );
```

So finally You need to read a little more about hooks: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks
and after this lecture You will find many answers how to get form submitted data like from this topic: [WordPress contact form 7 text value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429325/wordpress-contact-form-7-text-value-change)